# Trouble getting json back

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm using the current json structure of this:

```
jsonp = {"game":[
              {"id":"1","gameImage":"qqq.jpg"}
              ],
        "game":[
              {"id":"2","gameImage":"hhh.jpg"}
              ]
       }
```

I'm trying to just get back all the **gameImage** values. I tried the following but it just won't work. Any ideas?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="gameData.json"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {


  var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
      $.each(obj, function() {
          alert(this['gameImage']);
      });

});
        </script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first code you show is in the file (incorrectly) named `"gameData.json"`, what you're trying to parse isn't JSON (or JSONP), it's plain JavaScript.

So don't parse it.

Change

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
```

to

```
var obj = jsonp;
```

Notes :

- [JSON](http://json.org) is a text based data interchange format. Your confusion might come from the many young developers using non-sensical expressions like "JSON object"...
- You should avoid naming `jsonp` a variable holding a plain JavaScript object.

---

If you prefer to load a JSON file instead of executing a JavaScript file, then

1. remove the `"jsonp =` part to make it a real JSON file
2. remove the `script` element (as it's not JavaScript anymore)
3. load the JSON file using ajax

Here's how the JavaScript would be like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON("gameData.json", function(obj){
      $.each(obj, function() {
          alert(this['gameImage']);
      });
   });
});
```

or, if you can afford not supporting IE8 :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON("gameData.json", function(arr){
      arr.forEach(function(item){
          console.log(item.gameImage); // yes, prefer the console over alert
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Ah I see. I want to parse a real json file, so should I remove "jsonp =" from the json file?

Comment: If you want to make it a json file, yes, you must remove that part. But then you can't load it in a script element but using an ajax function. Do you want me to extend my answer to explain how to do that ?

Comment: Ok I've removed that. Should I still action the line changes you mentioned above? What I'd like to get back is for every game block, get back the gameImage value.

Comment: That's perfect thanks for this :) I've now come to realise that a real json file can't be loaded locally, which my game needs to. So I might go back to using your original answer and use it as a string state.